# Dependency Injection and loading application settings once only

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a custom class - "ApplicationConfigurationManager", which depends on my IDataRepository. Of course, the interface has a concrete implementation, in another assembly. So basically we have:

```
Business dll
 ApplicationConfigurationManager
 IDataRepository

EfDatabaseAccess dll
 EfDataRepository : IDataRepository

Client.exe
  ref EfDatabaseAccess dll
  ref Business dll
```

I want the ApplicationConfigurationManager to initialize only once for the entire application runtime life (i.e. Singleton), because it hits the database via IDataRepository. At the same time I want IDataRepository to resolve to EfDataRepository by Unity.

The two don't play well together. How do I keep some class alive, if it depends on Unity to resolve its dependencies.

Comment: Why would you want IDataRepository to function as a singleton?  If it's managing connections they should die as soon as their scope is done.

Comment: Not the IDataRepository. I'd like my Application Config Manager to be a singleton, as it is supposed to load only once (settings in the database table it depends on don't change often)

Comment: Since DI seems impossible with a Singleton, I'm thinking, maybe just implement some caching mechanism in the Application Management Class, instead of trying to make it a singleton. But then, I also have an ILogger and other one-time-init-only services and now it stops making sense to implement caching in each one of them. I really need some form of a singleton. But these object depend on interfaces which are resolved with Unity...

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Lifetime Managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx) in Unity to control the lifecycle per registered type.  In your case, it would look like the following:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataRepository, DataRepository>();

container.RegisterType<IApplicationConfigurationManager, ApplicationConfigurationManager>
    ("MyMapping", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: assuming the container is kept alive by, e.g. the MVC application, which initializes it in Application_Start?

Comment: @HristoYankov why would you not keep container alive? How you'd resolve controllers for example?

Comment: No, I'm just saying - the suggested approach will work, assuming the MVC framework keeps the container alive for me.

Comment: @HristoYankov I'm confused, are you questioning whether or not the container will be kept alive?  Of course it will be kept alive.  It would be awfully hard to do any dependency injection if it weren't.

Comment: @DavidL, sorry, I meant - Is the container created on Application Start and kept alive until IIS is reset, or is it recreated on every request. I am assuming the former.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like `Logger.Log("Some text")` but still able to setup and properly resolve dependencies with Unity.

You can use `Func<IMyInterface>` auto-registered by Unity when you register interfaces - using `Func` version lets you resolve object when you need to use it instead when you initialize the calls.

```
public static Func<IDbLogger> LoggerGetter {get;set}
public static static Log(string text)
{
    LoggerGetter().Log(text); // will resolve `IDbLogger` at this point
}

....
// during container initialization:
container.Register<IDbLogger>(....);
Logger.LoggerGetter = container.Resolve<Func<IDbLogger>>();
```

Notes:

- `Func<IMyInterface>` created by Unity container is essentially `()=>container.Resolve<IMyInterface>()`, so if you want you can just pass such lambda instead. Drawback is that you can't override registration of `Func<IMyInterface>` if you use lambda directly (rarely needed).
- this post does not goes into whether using singleton is good/bad idea - make your own calls
- same technique can be used when lifetime of objects that depend on each other does not match (i.e. Application and Invocation, or HttpRequest and Invocation). To solve that object with longer lifetime should take dependency on `Func<...>` providing other object and call it when needed.

Comment: thanks. Your post made me realize how bad Singleton is. My Client app will need to have 'magical' knowledge of initializing the Singleton. That's not intuitive.